# Phonegap server hangs

Tags: node.js, cordova

I'm in the process of developing an app for iPhone, using PhoneGap, and I'm using the PhoneGap developer tools provided for iPhone, that ports the built app to my local iPhone using a node server.

This was all work, and then without any apparent reason it suddenly stopped. Here's a screenshot.

It just hangs at this screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How many files in www folder have your project?

I had same problem when running phonegap serve.

I used bower to install my packages, and I noticed if I removed the folders of some of my project dependencies serve resumed to work again. One of my packages had more than 100 files (I needed only 2).

I made a cleanup and solved the problem.

I hope it helps.